# Firebase function - how to create multiple documents from different collections

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, triggers, google-cloud-functions

I am fairly new to writing functions and cannot figure out how to solve my issue or even search for it properly.

I have three collections:

current_projects

vendors

vendor_projects

when a new project is created I want the function to take all documents in vendors, add certain fields from them to vendor_projects, and include the project_id field that is created in current_projects.

Do I need a for loop to accomplish this or is there other syntax that could be utilized?

My current function is below.  This creates on document using the new project_id field but doesnt take any of the fields from vendors.  Any input is greatly appreciated.

```
exports.createProjVen = functions.firestore.document("/Current_projects/{id}")
.onCreate((snap, context)=>{
  console.log(snap.data());
  const id = snap.data().id;
  // const collection = context.params.Current_projects;
  // const id = context.params.id;

  const projectVendors = admin.firestore().collection("project_vendors");
  // const vendors = admin.firestore().collection("vendors");

  return projectVendors.doc(id).set({
    actual: "",
    budget: "",
    id: "23121",
    project_id: id,
    toggle: "true",
    type: "Fixtures",
    vendor_company: "tes",
    vendor_contact: "tes",
    vendor_email: "jj@j.com",
    vendor_id: "test",
    vendor_phone_number: "test"});
});
```

Adding more details:

When a new project is added it creates a record in current_projects.

[image]

I want the function to be able to query all documents in the vendor collection when a new record is created in current_projects.

[image]

From there, I want to grab the highlighted fields from the vendor documents, add the id from that was created from current_projects (highlighted in the first screen shot), and create a new document in project_vendors (third screen shot below) for every document in the vendors table.

[image]

Comment: You want to query all documents from `project_vendors` and then take some fields from all of them and add where? Can you share screenshot of all 3 collections to show sample documents and then explain ?

Comment: Thanks for responding @Dharmaraj.  I added more details.  Please let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to created a document in `project_vendors` collection for every vendor in `vendors` after a project is created then you can map an array of promises and then use `Promise.all()` as shown below:

```
exports.createProjVen = functions.firestore.document("/Current_projects/{id}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const docSnap = snap.data();
    const id = context.params.id;

    const vendorsSnap = await admin.firestore().collection("vendors").get();
    const vendorsData = vendorsSnap.docs.map((d) => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() }))
    
    const promises = [];
  
    const vendorPrsCol = admin.firestore().collection("project_vendors");
  
    vendorsData.forEach((vendor) => {
      const data = {
        projectId: id,
        email: vendor.email,
        // other vendor fields
      }
      
      promises.push(vendorPrsCol.add(data));
    })

    await Promise.all(promises);
  
    console.log("Vendor Projects added");
    return null;
  });
```